# Tcpdump saved file is empty even reporting that captured millions of packet

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tcpdump

I captured traffic on a server interface remotely by using ssh to send command to a shell script controlling Tcpdump.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to Start/Stop TCP
# Usage: ./ControlTCPdump.sh start|stop [filename]

CONSOLE_OUTPUT="tcpdump$( date +%m%d ).console"
HOST_NAME=`hostname`

#Default filename:
if [ "$2" = "" ]; then
    FILENAME="traffic.dmp"
else
    FILENAME=$2
fi

if [ "$1" = start ]; then
    echo $(date) $FILENAME >> $CONSOLE_OUTPUT
    if [ "" = "$(pidof tcpdump)" ]; then
        nohup tcpdump -s 96 -w $FILENAME -i em2 -n tcp > /dev/null &>> $CONSOLE_OUTPUT &
        echo [$HOST_NAME] TCPdump is started\!
    else
        echo [$HOST_NAME] There is runnung process. Kill All\!
        killall -q tcpdump #Quiet, don't talk
        sleep 1
        if [ "" = "$(pidof tcpdump)" ]; then
            echo [$HOST_NAME] Restarting TCPdump...
            nohup tcpdump -s 96 -w $FILENAME -i em2 -n tcp >/dev/null &>> $CONSOLE_OUTPUT &
            echo [$HOST_NAME] TCPdump is started\!
        else
            echo [$HOST_NAME] Error\! Cannot kill them\!
            exit 0
        fi
    fi
else 
    if [ "$1" = stop ]; then
        TD=`pidof tcpdump`
        if [ -n "$TD" ]; then
            kill "$TD"
        fi
        sleep 1
        if [ "" = "$(pidof tcpdump)" ]; then
            echo [$HOST_NAME] TCPdump is stopped\!
        else
            echo [$HOST_NAME] Error\! Cannot kill them\!
            exit 0
        fi        
    else
        echo [$HOST_NAME] Syntax error\!
        exit 0
    fi
fi
```

The report said that it already captured thousand of packets. But When I see the tcpdump cap file, it is empty and has problems when read with tcptrace.

```
...
Mon Mar 25 23:25:48 CET 2013 CapturedTraffic201303252230/Traffic30.dmp
tcpdump: listening on em2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size
96 bytes 1403831 packets captured 1403831 packets received by filter 0
packets dropped by kernel Mon Mar 25 23:27:28 CET 2013

CapturedTraffic201303252230/Traffic31.dmp tcpdump: listening on em2,
link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes 1378692 packets
captured 1378692 packets received by filter 0 packets dropped by
kernel
...
```

The phenomenon is like this one (I use "ls -l" to see file size):

```
...
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 105206180 Mar 25 16:37 Traffic05.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 117855276 Mar 25 16:39 Traffic06.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 109911288 Mar 25 16:40 Traffic07.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 121505444 Mar 25 16:42 Traffic08.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 110303300 Mar 25 16:43 Traffic09.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 120444026 Mar 25 16:45 Traffic10.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  98545664 Mar 25 16:46 Traffic11.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         0 Mar 25 16:48 Traffic12.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         0 Mar 25 16:50 Traffic13.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         0 Mar 25 16:51 Traffic14.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         0 Mar 25 16:53 Traffic15.dmp
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root         0 Mar 25 16:54 Traffic16.dmp
...
```

Sometime it worked and sometime it did not. Did anybody encounter this kind of problem before? thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: The disk is full but tcpdump did not tell me. I change to tshark and it told me that no space left. thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I tried your script and there are a couple of points (not relevant to your issue).

- you assign `HOSTNAME` (which is already set by default, by the way) and you always use HOST_NAME. Maybe you wanted to set `HOST_NAME` instead?
- the last `else` of the script should be a `fi`

That said, the files get written to the disk when they reach a certain amount in size (aka buffer). You can force the synchronization of with `sync`. Example:

```
# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root  4096 Mar 26 10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 elisiano users 4096 Mar 26 10:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 elisiano users 1327 Mar 26 10:49 ControlTCPdump.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root   119 Mar 26 10:51 tcpdump0326.console
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Mar 26 10:51 traffic.dmp
[root@pc-elisiano /home/elisiano/Projects/ctcpd ]# ls -al
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root  4096 Mar 26 10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 elisiano users 4096 Mar 26 10:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 elisiano users 1327 Mar 26 10:49 ControlTCPdump.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root   119 Mar 26 10:51 tcpdump0326.console
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     0 Mar 26 10:51 traffic.dmp
# sync
# ls -al
total 24
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root  4096 Mar 26 10:51 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 elisiano xbmc  4096 Mar 26 10:43 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 elisiano users 1327 Mar 26 10:49 ControlTCPdump.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root   119 Mar 26 10:51 tcpdump0326.console
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root  8192 Mar 26 10:51 traffic.dmp
```

Could you maybe paste the output of the console output of one time it didn't work?

Also, are you reaching the filesystem limit for file size?

To debug this you could lunch your tcpdump in a terminal multiplexer (such as screen or tmux) and let it run there (even if you detach your session). This way (when you re-attach the session) you can see any additional output.

Comment: Thank you Petrini.
I copy the shell script lacking of the last part.
The file size is at most 150MBs, I don't think it cause any problem. My maximum bandwidth is 1Gbs and I only take 96 bytes for each packet sending in the duration of 60s. It cannot exceed 150MBs for sure.

Comment: The code in the middle of the question is the console output of the time it didn't work. Its always report that it has captured tons of packet, but when I see the cap file, it haz 0 byte in size.

Comment: You are mistaken about the meaning of the sync command. It writes the block buffer cache to disk, not application local buffers to file descriptors.